# One Swift SpriteNode to approach another

Tags: sprite-kit, swift3

I have 2 sprite nodes. one is the player (red) and there is also another object (green). additionally there is an invisible area which I use for collision detection.

My intention is, that the green objects approaches the red player as soon as the player is within the blue rectangle.

[image]

Until now I set up the collision handling in a way that a SKAction is triggered when the player collides with the blue area. The SKAction moves the green object to the position to the player. This approach works as long as I do not work with texture changes, which are handled with a SKActionForever.

Here is my code I have:

```
                    let distance: CGFloat = fabs(platformNode1.position.x - player.position.x);                        
                    let moveToPlayer = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: player.position.x, y: platformNode1.position.y), duration: Double(distance/10))                        
                    let passengerAnimation = SKAction.group([moveToPlayer, animatePassengerAction])
                    animatePassengerAction = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.animate(with: passengerAnimation, timePerFrame: 0.1))
                    let removePassenger = SKAction.removeFromParent()                        
                    let setPassengerToOnBoard = SKAction.run({ () -> Void in
                        self.passengerOnBoard = true
                    })                        
                    let onBoardActionSequence = SKAction.sequence([passengerAnimation, removePassenger, setPassengerToOnBoard])                        
                    self.passenger.run(onBoardActionSequence, withKey: "isOnboarding")
```

My problem no is, that the SKAction sequence does never complete, since the sequence is looping "passengerAnimation" until forever. But I need this animation forever since this represents the animation of the walking passenger/object, which should be looped as long as the object approaches the player.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem? I am really stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the travel time or the passenger's movement, you should be able to compute the number of cycles needed and adjust the animation to that (and then you won't need to repeat forever)

For example:

```
let distance: CGFloat = fabs(platformNode1.position.x - player.position.x);                        
let moveToPlayer = SKAction.move(to: CGPoint(x: player.position.x, y: platformNode1.position.y), duration: Double(distance/10))                        

// distance/10 seconds * 0.1 second perFrame = distance number of frames.
// build a (repeating) array of the original animation frames with exactly the right number of frames for the distance.
let animationOnDistance = (0..<distance).map{passengerAnimation[$0 % passengerAnimation.count]}

let animatePassengerAction = SKAction.animate(with: animationOnDistance, timePerFrame: 0.1)

let passengerAnimation = SKAction.group([moveToPlayer, animatePassengerAction])
```